# ¿Cómo mantener el servicio de elasticsearch "active"

Tags: elasticsearch

Recién instalé el servicio de *elasticsearch* en mi máquina: lubuntu 18.04

Versión de Java:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Home de Java:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/bin
```

datos del yaml de elasticsearch:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

network:
  host: localhost

http:
  port: 9200
```

Inicio el servicio de elasticsearch:

```
$ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-11-01 11:52:14 -04; 4s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 20860 (java)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 4561)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           └─20860 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless

nov 01 11:52:14 Aspire systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
$
```

Ejecuté este curl para confirmar que todo está bien, pero falla:

```
$ curl localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Conexión rehusada
```

En unos segundos se cae elasticsearch:

```
$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: ailed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-11-01 11:53:29 -04; 54s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 20860 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20860 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

nov 01 11:52:14 Aspire systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
nov 01 11:53:29 Aspire systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov 01 11:53:29 Aspire systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

En en log `sudo cat /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log` sale esto:

```
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,013][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path ([file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.10.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-launchers-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-spatial3d-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-queries-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/hppc-0.7.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-spatial-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/plugin-cli-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-secure-sm-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jna-4.5.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-queryparser-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.8.10.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/t-digest-3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/plugin-classloader-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jts-core-1.15.0.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-backward-codecs-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-core-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-sandbox-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.9.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-grouping-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-suggest-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-spatial-extras-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-join-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/log4j-core-2.9.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/spatial4j-0.7.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-core-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-memory-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-analyzers-common-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-x-content-6.3.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.10.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-misc-7.3.1.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-highlighter-7.3.1.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:962) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:171) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,059][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,060][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot install system call filter because JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,062][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,073][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_NPROC because JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,073][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_AS beacuse JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:20,074][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_FSIZE because JNA is not available
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,346][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,759][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [J595XaZ] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda6)]], net usable_space [37.6gb], net total_space [46.6gb], types [ext4]
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,760][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [J595XaZ] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [unknown]
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,804][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [J595XaZ] node name derived from node ID [J595XaZ1Qe-z16o3HmSoSQ]; set [node.name] to override
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,805][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [J595XaZ] version[6.3.2], pid[21673], build[default/deb/053779d/2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-66-generic/i386], JVM[Private Build/OpenJDK Server VM/1.8.0_222/25.222-b10]
[2019-11-01T12:08:21,806][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [J595XaZ] JVM arguments [-Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.BaXAmeCA, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=deb]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,930][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,931][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,931][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,931][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,931][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,932][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,932][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,932][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,932][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,933][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,933][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,933][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [repository-url]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,934][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,934][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [tribe]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,934][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,935][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,935][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,935][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,936][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,936][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,936][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,936][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,936][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,937][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,937][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2019-11-01T12:08:39,939][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [J595XaZ] no plugins loaded
[2019-11-01T12:09:14,536][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [J595XaZ] parsed [0] roles from file [/etc/elasticsearch/roles.yml]
[2019-11-01T12:09:17,766][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [linux-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
[2019-11-01T12:09:17,795][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [linux-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [linux-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: ¿Usas Ubuntu 32-bit?

Comment: Si Ubuntu 32-bit y el elasticsearch 6.3.2 y descargué pero no he instalado el elasticsearch 6.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema al que haces referencia lo he tenido,

> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
>   Machine Learning is not available for [linux-x86]; you can use the
>   other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false
>   in elasticsearch.yml

y **se debe a que Elasticsearch únicamente es soportado en arquitecturas de 64 bits**, por lo tanto  Ubuntu 32-bit y el elasticsearch 6.3.2 no es una combinación que funcione.

De hecho esto esta especificado :

https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix

> **Actualmente solo soportamos y probamos arquitecturas x86_64.**

Comment: ¿Me puedes recomendar una versión mas vieja de elasticsearch que si funcione con 32bits?

Comment: Al parecer ya no existen esas versiones disponibles, te sugiero tratar si es posible descargar la versión 3 o 2 de esta forma: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu/ por ejemplo para la versión 3 :  > sudo apt -y install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/3.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-3.x.list

Comment: Encontré elasticsearch 2.3.3, me puede indicar un enlace o los pasos para desinstalar elasticsearch 6.3.2 de una manera segura

Comment: En internet puedes encontrar este proceso: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/digitalworkplacebasic/30/uninstalling-elasticsearch-603829319.html